# Installation of packages

Tags: installing, miktex

How can I install a package that doesn't exist in my MikTeX 2.9 package manager? I have downloaded it from CTAN and then created a folder named `ucharclasses` that contains the `ucharclasses.sty` and `ucharclasses.tex` at the path MikTeX → tex → latex.

However I still get the error `ucharclasses.sty` not found. I am a Windows user and I use MikTeX 2.9 and TexWorks, if that has any importance.

Comment: The package should be in your package manager, it is in mine.

Comment: There isn't in mine. I read there are licensing issues with the package therefore it doesn't exist in the manager

Comment: It also says on the [CTAN-page](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ucharclasses) that it's in MiKTeX. Have you synchronized your Repository in the Package Manager?

Comment: The package is part of MiKTeX 2.9, the latest version is from 2012-09-26. In contrast to the CTAN repository MiKTeX does not contain the `.sty`-file, but I do not know why. Both files should go into `tex\xelatex\ucharclasses`.

Comment: @Alexander It *should* contain `ucharclasses.sty`! If it doesn't, then it's a bug in the packaging; `ucharclasses.sty` should go in `tex\xelatex\ucharclasses`, while the `.tex` file should go in the `doc` subtree.

Comment: @egreg: This is strange. I looked with MiKTeX package manager and there was no `.sty`-file listed in the package contents (maybe it is automatically created). After installing the package there is now a `ucharclasses.sty` file in the right directory. So it should definitely work in the current MiKTeX 2.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install a "private" package somewhere in system, you always have to refresh the package database.

In MikTeX, you should have a program file called 'Settings'.
When you launch this program, you just have to click on the button named 'Refresh FNDB'.
Your private package has to be on the search path. You can use the page 'Roots' to add a path to your package.